# Using Revolut card in Thailand

Tags: money, thailand, exchange, atms

The most ATMs in Thailand charge 200 Baht for getting cash - [What is the best way to get Baht in Thailand?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/64388/what-is-the-best-way-to-get-baht-in-thailand/64516#64516) Also a lot of shops require at least 500 Baht bill to pay by credit card or charge additional fee. Is it possible to avoid fees using [Revolut](https://www.revolut.com/lt/about?lang=en) card?

Comment: It's treated like any other debit card (tho one with a very low withdrawal limit.) From my reading of their terms, they don't reimburse ATM fees like some other bank cards do. So without getting one myself and flying over to Thailand, I'm going to hazard a guess of "no."

Comment: As of the beginning of 2023 most ATMs in Thailand now charge 220 baht. The exception is Aeon who charges 150 baht. I've only paid by card at 7-Eleven so far and they accepted it for around 100 baht of snacks. I don't know if this is a change that happened during covid like it did in my home country, or if 7-Eleven is an exception to the general rule.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Roddy of the Frozen Peas was correct. It doesn't appear so according to their [FAQ >> Card >> Are there any fees? >> Revolut Transactions:](https://www.revolut.com/lt/faq?lang=en#are-there-any-charges)

> **ATM withdrawals:**  Free up to £200/ €200/ Fr200/ 800zl (or currency equivalent) per month. 
> `A` **`2% fee`** `applies thereafter.`

and

> **Currency exchange transactions:** Live market rate* with **`no fees,`**`up to £5,000/ €6,000/ Fr6,000/ 20,000zl (or currency equivalent)`**`per month`**.
>
> *A 0.5% fee applies thereafter* **

The only way to completely avoid atm fees is to:
a) the credit/debit card's issuing bank does not charge any fees for ATM cash withdrawals + foreign currency transactions (or reimburses fees).
b) the atm itself does not charge any fees OR the issuing bank *reimburses fees* charged by other bank.

Good luck finding such a debit card....they are rare.  Usually banks/credit unions catering specifically to the military/federal employees will have favorable no/low foreign transaction fees.  Certain platinum cards likely have some good terms also.